# Performance improvement in sql server by adding partitions

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a sql server table where I keep adding data on a daily basis. Most queries have a date filter. I would like to add a range partition based on date to improve query performance.

My questions are:
Do i need to keep adding partitions on a daily basis as new dates become available?
Is there a limit to the number of partitions one can add and beyond a certain number of partitions, do the performance improvement disappear?

Comment: This question would probably get a better response at https://DBA.stackexchange.com

Comment: Partitioning is generally not the fix for performance provided you have optimal indexing.